# Verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular

I don't think I quite understand how the declaration of components quite works in Angular. I have two modules `App` and `Navigation` and within NavigationModule I have a a few components, `navigation-underline` and `navigation-bar`. When I try to use `navigation-underline` within the `navigation-bar` component I get the `Verify that it is part of this module.` error

Here is the following code

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [NavigationBarComponent, NavigationUnderlineComponent]
})
export class NavigationModule { }


## navigation-bar.html
<a style="font-size: 6em;" routerLink="/">Blah Blah</a>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/">ABOUT</a>
  <a routerLink="/">RESUME</a>
</nav>
<app-navigation-underline></app-navigation-underline>
```

I tried to declare it in app module also and it didn't work nor should I need to do it because I only use `<app-navigation-underline>` within the NavigationModule. Not sure why I'm getting the error.

**EDIT**: Okay I seem to have solved it by exporting the `NavigationUnderlineComponent` in the NavigationModule and importing it in the `AppModule` but I don't quite understand why I need it.

**EDIT2**: Actually I didn't even need to export it, I just had to declare it in AppModule. Why do I need to declare this component in app module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out!

What I really wanted to do was use use navigation-underline only within the NavigationModule context. I achieved this in the following way...

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [NavigationBarComponent, NavigationUnderlineComponent],
  exports: [NavigationBarComponent]
})
export class NavigationModule { }
```

Notice that NavigationUnderlineComponent is not exported. And then in AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BlogIndexComponent,
    BlogPreviewCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NavigationModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This allows me to constrain navigation-underline to be only used within NavigationModule